# How to exclude a specific library from Android module (Library)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I built an Android library and published it on Jitpack.io, in this library I'm using some other libraries for debugging purposes such as Facebook Flipper and Hyperion but I don't want to export these libraries, meaning, I don't want these libraries' files to make its way to anyone who is going to use my library, How can I do that ?

Comment: You are saying that you don't want to give them a credit?

Comment: Not at all, I don't want the debugging tools to make their way because the app might also be using the same libraries and they will cause conflict and this actually happened, that's why I thought about excluding them.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to define gradle dependencies based on build or flavor. For example :

```
debugImplementation "example.debug:dependency"
```

Now when you build your artifact, you just build a non debug variant and the dependency will not be included.

You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
No, since I'm developing an Android library, I want one of the libraries that I'm using to be not exposed to my library's users (I want the app consuming my library to consume the library without two internal libraries to avoid conflict if the app is using the same library, which actually happened).

Comment: @AhmadMahmoudSaleh Did you manage to exclude library?

Comment: @Reena Yes, all you have to do is read the error and see which module to exclude, and write it as it was in the error message.
If you posted your error here, I can help you to solve it.